# Jframe help Using Boxlayout

Tags: java, swing

Hello guys :D i am trying to place a button in G-U-I when someone press a button, and i was able to do so. but i have a problem, first, in my code it seems the box layout is not working. i mean i want the button to appear beneath the add command button but it appears on right side of it (because of flow layout i guess).
code-

```
static JLabel name=new JLabel("TESTING123");
static JButton add=new JButton("Add New Command");
static JButton a=new JButton("Press Me To Set Command Number 1");
static JPanel panel=new JPanel();
static JFrame frame=new JFrame("TEST FRAME");

public static void init(){



    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(),BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));//THIS IS NOT WORKING
    //======================================================SOME FRAME PROPERTIES

    panel.add(name);
    panel.add(add);

    //======================================================ADDING TO PANELS
    add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            panel.add(a);
            frame.repaint();
            frame.validate();

        }
    });
    //======================================================LISTENERS



    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setSize(450,500);
    frame.setVisible(true);


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i mean i want the button to appear beneath the add command button but it appears on right side of it

```
panel.add(a);
```

The default layout of a JPanel is a FlowLayout. If you want the component added below, then you need to change the layout of the panel to be a BoxLayout.

Or, instead of adding the component to the panel you can add it to the content pane of the frame since that is already using a BoxLayout:

```
frame.add(a);
```

> frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(),BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));//

Changing the layout of the frame doesn't affect the layout of the panel.

Comment: if i do  panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(),BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)); i get error == Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: BoxLayout can't be shared

Comment: @thvardhan: he didn't tell you to do that. Re-read his answer.

Comment: No. you want the "panel' to use the BoxLayout. The frame or the content pane has nothing to do with the layout of the panel. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) for a simple working example.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels oh sorry i dint saw that